# Angular service callback executing only once

Tags: javascript, angularjs

**controller**

```
angular.module('eateryApp')
        .controller('RestaurantsController',RestaurantsController);

    RestaurantsController.$inject=['yelp','$routeParams'];

    function RestaurantsController(yelp,$routeParams) {

        var rstrntsCtrl=this;
        rstrntsCtrl.restaurants={};
        rstrntsCtrl.inputs=$routeParams.term;
        yelp.retrive(rstrntsCtrl.inputs,function(data) {
            alert("wfw");
            rstrntsCtrl.restaurants=data.businesses;
        });
    }
```

**service**

```
angular.module('eateryApp')
        .factory('yelp',yelp);

    yelp.$inject=['$http'];
    function yelp($http) {

        var factory={
            retrive:retrive
        };

        return factory;


        function retrive(inputs,callback){

            var method = 'GET';
            var url = 'http://api.yelp.com/v2/search';
            var params = {
                    callback: 'angular.callbacks._0',
                };

            $http.jsonp(url, {params: params}).success(callback);
        }
    }
```

I wrote this controller and service for a particular page, let say "/page". when i go to that page("/page") everything works and callback executes. But when i go to to "/index" after "/page" and come back again to "/page" ajax call fires but callback in controller is not executed. can some one spot the error

A plnkr with similar example
http://plnkr.co/edit/fswywkpsH6xl5XU0YplK?p=preview

In this plnkr the callback in profile controller executes only once

Comment: You said that in the second scenario the "ajax call fires", I assume you mean that it was a 20x response? If it is a 40x or 50x response, then the `.success(...)` will never be called. Instead, the `.error(...)` function attached to `$http.jsonp(...)` will be called. Otherwise, it all looks good (except the fact that you don't use the `inputs` function parameter at all in the `retrieve` function--is that intended?).

Comment: any thing wrong with this?: angular.callbacks._0

Comment: I'm not sure. I've never used the yelp API, or jsonp for that matter. I was looking at it purely from an Angular point-of-view. I assumed you were calling the API correctly.